# How to build out this complex Array based on this Simple Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/tuhgns3q/

My simple object:

```
{
    portfolio: "AAPL",
    t1_tag1: "1111",
    t2_tag1: "2222",
    t3_tag1: "3333",
    ticker1: "AA",
    ticker2: "GOOG",
    ticker3: "AAPL"
}
```

The desired end result below. Array with Objects containing Array of Objects:

```
[
    0:Object {
        tags: [
            0:Object {
                t1_tag1: "1111"
            }
        ]
        ticker: ticker1
    },
    1:Object {
        tags: [
            0:Object {
                t2_tag2: "2222"
            }
        ]
        ticker: ticker2
    },
    3:Object {
        tags: [
            0:Object {
                t3_tag3: "3333"
            }
        ]
        ticker: ticker3
    }
]
```

Is there a simplier way to accomplish this with **[_lodash](https://lodash.com/)**?

Comment: So you just discard the `portfolio` attribute?

Comment: On what portion of data do you like to group the input? On the last character, in this case a digit? So the input object in the question must be updated, as it contains 3x tag1, but output differs.

Comment: @dsuess Yes, so if there is a ticker3, then all tags that start with `t3_` need to be grouped into the tags Array inside of ticker3's object. Would it helped if I renamed the keys differently? Say for example `t1_ticker1` & `t1_tag1` or `t3_ticker3` & `t3_tag1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using just vanilla JavaScript and no lodash or underscore:

```js
function expand(simple) {
    var outerArray = [], innerArray,
        outerIndex = 1, innerIndex,
        outerObject, innerObject;

    while (("ticker" + outerIndex) in simple) {
        innerArray = [];
        innerIndex = 1;

        while (("t" + outerIndex + "_tag" + innerIndex) in simple) {
            innerObject = {};

            innerObject["t" + outerIndex + "_tag" + innerIndex] = simple["t" + outerIndex + "_tag" + innerIndex];
            innerArray.push(innerObject);

            innerIndex++;
        }

        outerObject = {
            tags: innerArray,
            ticker: simple["ticker" + outerIndex]
        };

        outerArray.push(outerObject);

        outerIndex++;
    }

    return outerArray;
}

console.log(expand({
    portfolio: "AAPL",
    t1_tag1: "1111",
    t2_tag1: "2222",
    t3_tag1: "3333",
    ticker1: "AA",
    ticker2: "GOOG",
    ticker3: "AAPL"
}));
```

Comment: Beautiful! Didn't think of using a `while` loop, in fact I never have! Thanks! :D Read through it all and got it...